# Cookie code not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to set a modal popup using jquery ui and cookies that will open a popup on the home page only once when a user visits the site. Here is my code below

```
$(document).ready( 
function () {
if (($.cookie('visited') === null)|| ($.cookie('visited') === undefined )) {
 $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
      width:700,
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      show: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration:500
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "blind",
    duration: 500
  }
    });
  });

$.cookie('visited') = 'visited';
}

else if($.cookie('visited') === 'visited')  {
alert('its here ');
return false;

}


});
```

I know that the modal code is working and I can't figure out why the cookie code is not working.

It works fine on JSBIN  but not on the site that I want it to run in. This is the [site](http://thermalimageireland.ie/epages/950003979.sf/en_IE/?ObjectPath=/Shops/950003979/Categories) that it's supposed to work on .

Answer (score 0):

try to remove $(function()) from if:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (($.cookie('visited') === null)|| ($.cookie('visited') === undefined )) {
        $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
        ...
```

Comment: doesn't work and I don't think it has any relation to my problem

Comment: ok, then try to set cookie by calling $.cookie('visited', 'visited')